# Using Traditional Chinese with AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, character-encoding, amazon-dynamodb

I have a mobile app that stores data in dynamoDB tables. There is a group of users in Taiwan that attempted to store there names in the database. when the data is stored it become garbled. I have researched this and see that it is because dynamoDB uses UTF encoding while tradional chinese uses big 5 text encoding. How do I setup dynamoDB so that it will store and recall the proper characters??

[image: example of garbled text]

Comment: You either convert the big 5 encoding to utf-8 before writing it to a string field in DynamoDB or store it as binary information would be my guess but I've never worked with that particular encoding. I'd also check that this is not a weird browser display issue by reading the data with an SDK from the table and writing them to a file or something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is displaying in the app that matches what I see in the browser but will double check that its actually stored this way but I do think the way to go is converting to utf-8 before writing the data.

Answer (score 1):

So you start with a string in your head. It's a sequence of Unicode characters. There's no inherent byte encoding to the characters. The same string could be encoded into bytes in a variety of ways. Big5 is one. UTF-8 is another.

When you say that Traditional Chinese uses Big5, that's not entirely true. It may be commonly encoded in Big5, but it could be in UTF-8 instead, and UTF-8 has this cool property that it can encode all Unicode character sequences. That's why it's become the standard encoding for situations where you don't want to optimize for one character set.

So your challenge is make sure to carefully control the characters and encodings so that you're sending UTF-8 sequences to DynamoDB. The standard SDKs would do this correctly as long as you're creating the strings as basic strings in them.

You also have to make sure you're not confusing yourself when you look at the data. If you look at UTF-8 bytes but in a way where you're interpreting them as Big5 then it's going to look like gibberish, or vice versa.

You don't say how they're loading the data. If they're starting with a file, could be that. You'd want to read the file in a language saying it's Big5, then you'll have the string version, and then you can send the string version and rely on the SDK to correctly translate to UTF-8 on the wire.

I remember when I first learned this stuff it was all kind of confusing. The thing to remember is a capital A exists as an idea (and is a defined character in Unicode) and there's a whole lot of mechanisms you could use to put that letter into ones and zeros on disk. Each of those ways is an encoding. ASCII is popular but EBCDIC was another contender from the past, and UTF-16 is yet another contender now. Traditional Chinese is a character set (a set of characters) and you can encode each those characters a bunch of ways too. It's just a question of how you map characters to bits and bytes and back again.

Comment: Thanks for your response... I better understand the concept behind the issue but still having the problem. The flutter app form data arrears to be correct when its entered but then the display changes once its saved. I have not found a solution yet... told the client to tell everyone to just use simplified Chinese for now but being in Taiwan where traditional Chinese is the norm they are not too happy about it.. perhaps someone will make a package for Dart or node that will let me make the conversion

Comment: This stuff is tricky because any step along the way can corrupt the data. It's also easy to look at correct data and think it's corrupted just because of an error in how you're viewing it. It's really best to drop down and look at the byte sequences and verify you're getting the right bytes at every step. For you, you first need to make sure whatever you're using on the server-side actually gets the string correctly, then move to the next processor. You can also use a sample string like an n with a tilde on it (ñ) to just make it a super simple use case for the first pass.